# Operand types are incompatible ("double*" and "int")

Tags: c++, int, double, operands

Getting this error from my code. I had looked at similar questions on here but wasn't able to see why mine wasn't working (most answers involved chars and people using " instead of ', which wasn't really helpful to me). Not sure what I'm missing here. Edit: To be a little more specific it's the ">" sign in my if statement that is giving me trouble. My code is below:

```
    int main()
{
int numGrades = 0;
double *scores = nullptr;
double total = 0;
cout << fixed << setprecision(1);

cout << "How many grades would you like to enter? ";
cin >> numGrades;
if (numGrades < 0)
{
    cout << "Error, please enter positive values only: ";
    cin >> numGrades;
}
scores = new double[numGrades];
for (int x = 0; x <= numGrades; x++)
{
    cout << "Please enter student " << (x + 1) << "'s score: ";
    cin >> scores[numGrades];
    if (scores < 0 && scores > 100)     //ERROR IS HERE
    {
        cout << "Please enter a value between 0 and 100: ";
        cin >> scores[numGrades];
    }
}
```

Comment: Scores is a pointer, you've forgotten to dereference it

Comment: Also, you're running off the end of the array, resulting in undefined behavior and corrupted memory, because your `for` loop iterates one too many.

Comment: Also, once you've done that what you've written doesn't make much sense. Did you mean loop through the array and find the min/max, then compare with 0/100?

Comment: @OMGtechy Sorry, I'm new to this, I'm not sure what you mean D:

Comment: @OMGtechy the if statement is supposed to just error trap and make sure that I don't input a value below 0 or above 100

Comment: That's not what it does. It compared the address of scores with 0 and 100 (hence the error message). Sounds like you need to brush up on your pointers and dynamically allocated arrays, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

`cin >> scores[numGrades];` is assigning data outside of the allocated memory; anything after that is undefined behavior.

Did you mean `cin >> scores[x];`?

Comment: Whoops! Good catch! That is in fact what I wanted.

Comment: That is not the only issue. I'm driving, can't write more now

Comment: Okay, thank you for that. Be safe! No texting and driving lol

Answer (score 0):

```
if (scores < 0 && scores > 100)     //ERROR IS HERE
{
    cout << "Please enter a value between 0 and 100: ";
    cin >> scores[numGrades];
}
```

That's what you wrote. However a number cannot be smaller than 0 and larger than 100 so this is how you should fix it.

```
if (scores < 0 || scores > 100)
{
    cout << "Please enter a value between 0 and 100: ";
    cin >> scores[numGrades];
}
```